# Starting or stopping an agent through another agent

Tags: agent, volttron

I currently have a volttron agent that periodicially downloads some data from the web in the form of a csv. I would like to use the DataPublisher example to take that csv data and push it to pubsub. However, from looking at the code, it seems like the DataPublisher is designed to run once, automatically, as soon as the agent starts up.

So my question them becomes, is there a way to start up the datapublisher from the original agent (which would itself have some sort of timer or loop)? I would then also need to stop it afterwards.

If I can't do this, my alternatives seem to be modifying the datapublisher to work on a schedule, or altering my other agent to publish the data from the csvs to pubsub.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this is to expose an RPC method on the data publisher that either accepts a filename to publish.  When this is called it would change the filename to publish and "start" the publishing of the data.  The data publisher agent would always be running so there isn't a true restarting of the publisher.

The other agent (The one the downloaded the data?) would then just need to "kick off" the publishing through the rpc call.

This sounds like a very good feature that could be committed back to the VOLTTRON repository if you saw fit.